# finding the value of the sum $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{7^{n}}{8^{n}+2^{n}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I am concerned with finding the value of the sum $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{7^{n}}{8^{n}+2^{n}}$. There may be some easy way to do this, but I have not found a way to compute this sum, and ones like it. I cannot figure out how to turn it into a single easy-to-calculate exponential, but I am wondering if there is another way. I already know that this sum is convergent, but I want to know exactly how to calculate its value. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to calculate the sum explicitly?

Comment: Do you want to know if this series is convergent or do you want to know its actual sum? The series is convergent which DonAnotnio pointed out, but to find the sum is a different story.

Comment: Even Wolfram returns a decimal approximation. Not all sums can be explicitly evaluated. This may be one of those.

Comment: Is there any way to tell **when** they can't be explicitly evaluated? I'd appreciate a rule of some type.

Comment: No, there is no such thing that we can look at the series, apply some prelimary trick and determine that the sum can be determined or not. Fact is that determining whether or not the series is (absolute) convergent is something math people can do quite easily, buth then the frustration kicks in: Knowing that a sum exists but not having the means to find it. Series is an unfinished chapter in the world of math.

Comment: Well thanks, I appreciate your help, and I'll be inspired for the rest of the day!

Comment: It's very unlikely that there's any closed form for this constant; indeed, even the simpler constant $\sum\frac1{2^n+1}$ isn't known to have any closed form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

$$\frac{7^n}{8^n+2^n}\le\left(\frac 78\right)^n\;,\;\;\text{and}\;\;\left|\frac 78\right|<1$$

Comment: It seems to OP wants to calculate the value of the series. (Seems a bit vague what he wants, actually.)

Comment: I am looking forward to that answer...

Comment: Yes, I noticed that and began editing, but I got stuck: it isn't, apparently, as easy as I thought.

Comment: Me too :)${}{}$

Comment: What I want is a way to calculate this series. I know that it's convergent, but I want to know how to calculate its convergence.

Comment: Then it is more precise to write "I want to know what its **sum** is", @recursiverecursion

Comment: You're right, I'll edit it right now.